# Can the features of Dell OpenManage be replaced by Microsoft System Center?

Tags: dell, system-center, dell-openmanage

I'm new to both OpenManage and System Center, but it sounds as if they're geared towards similar problems/goals. Are the features comparable enough that OpenManage can be forgone completely in favor of System Center products?

Specifically I'm hoping to achieve storage monitoring and remote administration, although if someone with experience with both wants to provide a quick compare/contrast (objective, of course) I won't complain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Openmange is designed to specifically work with dell hardware (similarly to HP SIM).  SCOM will utilize either in order to resolve issues so long as the management pack is installed.  For openmanage the management pack is [here](http://support.us.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?fileid=229201)

Comment: Fabulous. If this is anything like an mmc snapin, I'll be happy. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I have no experience with system center, but I really doubt it can manage dell (or any vendor) specific hardware the way OMSA does. Not to mention centralised firmware updates you can do using IT-assistant (OMSA management node).

Systems like MSSC are geared towards OS level monitoring and management, while OMSA is there to monitor and support a specific set of hardware.